# How can I read XML from URL using SQL Server - reverse geocoding

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I created below function to retrieve data from XML. I want to get formatted_address from the generated XML. How to get required result? I got NULL value. I want to get required result only using function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetLocation]
 (@latt VARCHAR(150), @lont VARCHAR(150)) 
 RETURNS varchar(max) 
 AS 
  BEGIN 
DECLARE @output NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @URL VARCHAR(8000) 
DECLARE @Response NVARCHAR(1024)
DECLARE @XML XML
DECLARE @Obj INT 
DECLARE @Result INT
DECLARE @HTTPStatus INT
DECLARE @ErrorMsg VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ConvertVar VARCHAR(8000)
DECLARE @lat VARCHAR(150) 
DECLARE @lon VARCHAR(150)

SET @lat = @latt
SET @lon = @lont

SET @URL ='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=23.56320001,46.66140002'

EXEC sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHttp', @obj OUT
EXEC sp_OAMethod @obj, 'open', NULL, 'GET', @URL, false
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Obj, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Obj, send, NULL, ''
EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @obj, 'ResponseText', @Response OUTPUT

SET @Response = replace(@Response, '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>', '')    
SET @XML = convert(xml,@Response)
SET @output = (SELECT   
                   T.c.value('formatted_address[1]','nvarchar(500)')                    
               FROM   
                   @XML.nodes('reversegeocode/result[1]') T(c))

RETURN @output
END
```

Comment: For starters, you can't EXEC anything within a function

Comment: @JohnCappelletti i want formatted_address from given URL in sql function if you have suggestion please tell me

Comment: In a function, you would have to go down the road of CLR.